# Talend: Append Excel file many times

Tags: excel, talend

I want to join 2 flows of data using Talend Data Integration, the result of the join will be written in many sheets in the same Excel file,

```
                       some filtered outputs--------- Excel_file1.sheet1
                       /
                      /
 ------main-------tMap--------- inner join result--------Excel_file1.sheet2
                 /    \
                /      \
          lookup        inner join reject----------Excel_file1.sheet3
```

The problem is that i didnt get the data written in the Excel file, and while the job running i see that the Excel file size is growing and then resetted to 0 many times. I have also tried to store output into `tHashOutput` and write its content later in the same job but that didnt make difference, does there any limitation to write data to Excel using Talend ?

Comment: in tFileOutputExcel component there is a setting "Append Existing File" you have to enable this for all of your tFileOutputExcel components - then it should not overwrite existing data. Better before you go to tMap subjob you can have a job to touch this output file so that it gets created.

Comment: @garpitmzn the setting is enabled and the problem is not about settings.

Comment: ok, then instead of you doing the write in parallel, do it sequentially..this would clarify the doubt that it fails in parallel, but works in sequential order. As you say if excel does not support concurrent access, then even if talend tries to do it, it actually is sequenctial process. My suggestion would be to first try out whether writing to different sheets of same file in parallel and sequential whether works or not with talend

Comment: You should check out jlollings tFileExcel  components

Comment: @BalazsGunics I cant find jlollings in the [component](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/13.27+tFileOutputExcel)

Comment: Look for excel on exchange: https://exchange.talend.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

tHashInput_1(read records from tHashOutput_1)---tFileOutputExcel(file1, sheet1)

tHashInput_2(read records from tHashOutput_2)---tFileOutputExcel(the same file, sheet2

Greetings.

Comment: I have mentioned that in my question i tried that friend !